# Dash Cytoscape: Is it possible to make colors of nodes change upon click by user?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I currently have the following Network Graph. The blue nodes belong to class 'mNodes' and the pink node belongs to class 'vNodes'. Is there a way to change the colour of any node dynamically when the user clicks on it? (e.g. When user clicks on node with label '55315' its colour changes to red.)

[image]

The code I used to construct my network graph is as follows:

```
# Node Elements
default_nodes = (
[{'classes': 'vNodes', 
    'data':{'id': v, 'label': v}} for v in df1.vFamilyID.unique()]+
[{'classes': 'mNodes',
    'data': {'id': m, 'label': m}} for m in df1.mFamilyID]
)

# Edge Elements
default_edges = [{'data': {'source': x, 'target': y}} for x,y in zip(df1.vFamilyID,df1.mFamilyID)]  

default_elements=(default_nodes+default_edges)

default_stylesheet=[
    # Class Selectors
    {
        'selector':'.vNodes',
        'style': {
            'background-color': '#CA8EB0',
            'label': 'data(label)'
        },
    },

    {
        'selector':'.mNodes',
        'style': {
            'background-color': '#5EB5C9',
            'label': 'data(label)'
        },
    },
]

cyto.Cytoscape(id='interaction-overview',
               elements=default_elements,
               stylesheet=default_stylesheet)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can i ask did you ever figure this out, I have the same issue thanks.

Comment: No, I have yet to figure this out.